# 'Error: INSERT INTO' Unspecific INSERT Error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert $_POST data that I have stored in variables to be stored in my database.  The connection to the database is fine, however, I'm getting the following error

> Error: INSERT INTO users (user_id, password, bankpin, auth, ip) VALUES ('sadasd', 'asdasd', '3434', '324234', '76.68.85.19')

So far I've tried inserting single and double quotes in various places such as around the table name and fields, however, I receive the same error.

Here is my php code:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, password, bankpin, auth, ip) VALUES ('$user_id', '$password', '$bankpin', '$auth', '$ip')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: You should use prepared statements with parameters instead of substituting variables, to protect against SQL-injection.

Comment: What is the Output of  `$conn->error`?

Comment: What happens if you copy the query and execute it by hand?

Comment: what is `user_id` column ? that is string?

Comment: There is no output from $conn->error.  Also if I copy the query by hand it doesn't work in my phpMyAdmin.  The format is different, however, that format returns the same result as I previously posted. user_id is type varchar and is being passed a string.

Comment: @JoshuaBrown *it doesn't work* means you get an error message? If yes, post it here

Comment: I like the security features, storing *user_id, password, bankpin* together is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Can you show your Table Structure

Comment: "it doesn't work" sounds pretty strange. Are you sure that there is no error message?

Comment: The bank pin is _probably_ an integer, not a string. That said, MySQL allows numbers to be enclosed in string, so this should not be the problem you encounter. Can you edit your question and include the definition of table `user`? (The CREATE TABLE statement.) That should clear it up quickly.

Comment: How do you initialize `$conn`? Does it _really_ return `TRUE` on success (and not the number of inserted rows, for example)? You have a very strict equality test `===` in your code.

Comment: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score -2):

user is type of integer, so pass $userid without quotes.

Try this

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, password, bankpin, auth, ip) VALUES ($user_id, '$password', '$bankpin', '$auth', '$ip')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: What have you changed? What makes you think that the change solves the problem? Please append such explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: user id is type of integer, so pass $userid without quotes.

Comment: According to the comment section: "user_id is type varchar"